# Display HTML formatted text from Rich Text multi-line column in SharePoint list column formatted with JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, json-formatting, column-formatting, multiple-lines-of-text

In SharePoint Online modern page I am trying to remove the styling that causes a white overlay and hides most of the text using the following JSON column formatting, so that the column height will be adjusted to display the full text of the column.

When previewing the changes with the following JSON formatting the full text is displayed and the background is removed but the text is not displayed with the applied formatting and all the HTML tags are displayed as if the text area's HTML has been encoded.

Is there any way to format SharePoint column with JSON and retain the formatted display of the text?

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
       "style": {
        "background": "none",
        "display":"initial",
        "overflow": "visible"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, rich multiline text fields are not supported within json column formatting. You could read this article: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/issues/88

The only workaround is using "plain text" instead in column settings.

Comment: I kind of figured this was the case because I had tried to use various DOMParsers and implement custom functions but SharePoint blocked the usage of all of them.  Unfortunately a requirement for this is that the text must be formatted because it contains critical links and details in the HTML formatting. Looks like building a SPFx extension to control the SharePoint modern page is the only way to go.  Thanks for confirming